# IE not loading fonts on Page refresh for HTTPS

Tags: internet-explorer, https, fonts

I am working on a web application using angular for frontend and Java for backend. I used swiss-721-light-condensed-bt as font.
The code I used is:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Swis721CnBT';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url('../../../resources/fonts/swiss-721-light-condensed- 
   bt.eot'),url('../../../resources/fonts/Swiss 721 Condensed BT.ttf');
}
```

When I deployed the application on http then it worked fine for Internet Explorer but when I deployed the same on
https then for IE, it's showing odd behaviour. When I load a page by directly refreshing the url, the font is not
applied but when I go to the page url through some internal links, the font is applied.
It happens only on https.

I tried finding it on forums, but didn't get any helpful solution.

Same kind of questions are posted already but I didn't get any working solution.

Thank you..

Comment: Only in IE? In Chromium, on many sites fonts are not being loaded because they are going through HTTP instead of HTTPS. You should get a bunch of errors in console about it. If only on IE, maybe it has something to do with caching? Try to give different font-faces (like add `?protocol=https`) when connecting through HTTPS.

Comment: It's only happening with IE on page reload only. When I go to the page through some internal links, it's applying the font.

Comment: has to be some problem with caching then (probably), try my other solution ... add to code different css when from https

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue today and found a soultion here: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/7681 (by willyelm on 23 Jan 2016)

So I'm quoting this solution here:

---

I had the same issue if you are running a https server with apache and have set:

```
Cache-Control: no-store
```

you need to remove it.

if for security reasons you still need to set no-store you can add this rule to the server apache conf:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

basically you are going to allow IE to store the cache with the font files for 1 hour. which wont affect the security.